# A question on the topic vectors.

Tags: vectors

The vector $\hat i+x\hat j+3\hat k$ is rotated through an angle $\theta$ and doubled in magnitude, then it becomes $4\hat i+(4x-2)\hat j+2\hat k$. The values of $x$ are?

I thought the rotation won't be of any significance and did like $√(1+x^2+9) = 2√(16+(4x-2)^2+4)$
But then I am getting the wrong answer. Please help.

Comment: To get the vector form of the force, if we call the vector $\textbf{w}$ then we have, $$\textbf{w} = \|\textbf{w}\| (\cos \omega, \sin \omega) = 34 (\cos \omega, \sin \omega) $$ where $\omega$ is the angle that the vector makes with the positive $x$-axis. So you need more information about the force vector, usually a bearing is given w.r.t the axes.

Answer (score 2):

The rotation indeed is of no significance. You just need to put factor $2$ to the left-hand side of the equation insted of the right-hand side.

Comment: I think the rotation does matter. Based on the calculations I came up with below, if you were to rotate that vector and then scale by a factor of $2$, there is now way that the resulting vector can have $2$ for its $z$-coordinate. It must be $6$.

Comment: @Faraad Armwood Rotation does have significance but if you see the magnitude you wont see a difference. Like take a vector and rotate it by any angle its magnitude wont change as its rotating in a circle.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply the rotation matrix in $3$-space and then just multiply the resulting vector by a factor of $2$. Calling this vector $\textbf{v}$ we have,

$$\textbf{v}=2 \cdot \begin{pmatrix} \cos \theta & \sin \theta &0 \\ - \sin \theta & \cos \theta & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ x \\ 3 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 4 \\ 4x-2 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Hey i had a doubt. Can u please answer it in the comments section? My doubt is if a force of 34N acts along AP where A(2,2,4)  and P(10,2,-11) then how do we get the vector form of the force.?

Comment: Yes I'm sure its $2$

Comment: By matrix multiplication, the last entry should be $6$. I missed the multiplication by $2$ for the doubling of the magnitude. If this is not a typo, I will delete my answer because there is clearly some misunderstanding. To rotate a vector in three space, you just apply the matrix I presented. To scale the magnitude you just multiply the vector by that scalar since the metric we use just pulls of scalars (in abs. value form).

Comment: well according to the question paper, it's 2

Comment: I've read many things with typos. Like I said, I don't know if that's the case, but judging from the actual algebra above, it seems as though we are missing something.

Comment: maybe the question paper was wrongly typed

Comment: Nothing in the question indicates that the rotation is in the $xy$ plane.